# getting type error on nav topic from move base

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update:
So I think my question is if ekf is a combined odometry why does move base not accept it in its published type , as a pose. How would I use the combined odometry if not in move base. Is this what the RoadMap part of the ekf webpage is talking about,yes?

Any ideas on what this error is means? Is this ekf node?

```
[ERROR] [1386956256.093192603, 0.774000000]: Client [/move_base] wants topic /rrbot_combined_odom/odom to have datatype/md5sum [nav_msgs/Odometry/cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7], but our version has [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped/953b798c0f514ff060a53a3498ce6246]. Dropping connection.
```

my launch file is:

```
<launch>

  <!-- Use simulation time from gazebo -->
  <rosparam param="use_sim_time=true"/>

  <!-- Load robot description here ; used by rviz / rqt_gui -->
  <param name="robot_description" 
              command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find rrbot_description)/urdf/rrbot.xacro'" />

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" 
                 args="-.1 0 .1 0 0 0  base_link tower_link 10" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link2_broadcaster" 
                 args="-.1 0 .2 0 0 0  tower_link hokuyo_frame 10" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link3_broadcaster" 
                 args="-.1 0 .2 -1.57 0 -1.57  tower_link camera_frame 10" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link4_broadcaster" 
                 args="-.13 -.13 .1 0 0 0  base_link left_wheel 10" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link5_broadcaster" 
                 args="-.13  .13 .1 0 0 0  base_link right_wheel 10" />



  <!-- Start rqt : note rrbot.rviz file must reside in launch dir -->
  <node name="rqt_gui" pkg="rqt_gui" type="rqt_gui" respawn="true">
  </node>

  <!-- load the controllers -->
  <!-- and Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
  <rosparam file="$(find rrbot_control)/config/rrbot_control.yaml" command="load"/>
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="true"
    output="screen" ns="/rrbot" args="--namespace=/rrbot
                      joint1_position_controller
                      joint2_position_controller"/>

  <!-- ******************************************************************************************** -->


  
  <!-- start mapping server and  pass odom frame : creates map from laser -->
  <node name="gmapping_node" pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping"  output="screen" respawn="true">
   <param name="occ_thresh"  value="0.05"/>
   <param name="map_update_interval"  value="0.05"/> 
  </node>


  <!-- Moves robot based on goal command : Listen for goals posted as twist to robot base -->
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" name="move_base" output="screen" respawn="true">
    <param name="controller_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
    <rosparam file="$(find rrbot_control)/config/move_base/costmap_common_params.yaml" 
              command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find rrbot_control)/config/move_base/costmap_common_params.yaml" 
              command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find rrbot_control)/config/move_base/local_costmap_params.yaml" 
              command="load"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find rrbot_control)/config/move_base/global_costmap_params.yaml" 
              command="load"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find rrbot_control)/config/move_base/base_local_planner_params.yaml" 
              command="load"/>
    <remap from="odom" to="/rrbot_combined_odom/odom"/>
  </node>

  <!-- Take gazebo model state and setup map-odom-base_link-senors transforms -->
  <node pkg="rrbot_control" type="robot_odometry" name="rrbot_odometry" output="screen" respawn="true"/>

  <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="rrbot_combined_odom">
    <param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="freq" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
    <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
    <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
    <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
    <param name="debug" value="true"/>
    <param name="self_diagnose" value="true"/>
    <remap from="imu_data" to="/rrbot/imu_data"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110286/getting-type-error-on-nav-topic-from-move--base./) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I added a translation of the odom_combined from a PoseWithCovarienceStamped to navigation odometry.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yalan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30703/yalan/) on 2017-10-16**:
Hi munziata, can you tell us how do you add a translation of the odom_combined from a PoseWithCovarienceStamped to sensor_msgs/Odometry? Thanks in advance and best regards.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2017-10-16**:
Sorry .... that project is long gone  now....I did not save the code.